# FITNESSE VERSION CONTROL

Tags: fitnesse

When FITNESSE is started with command -e 0, then by default the .zip folders are not created.
Now how can we track the version of WIKI pages in FITNESSE 
java -cp  !CLASSPATH!  fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain -p 9090  -e 0

Answer (score 0):

I usually use 'normal' version control (e.g. Git or Subversion) on the wiki files in the project. This also has the advantage that you choose when to commit the changes you make (i.e. not each change/edit is committed, but only when one or more pages are 'done' and tried locally) and you can provide explicit messages what was changed and why in that commit.

You probably don't want to store all files in the wiki in version control, but only the test pages and suites you make and the files in the 'files section'. The .gitignore file I usually use can be found at: https://github.com/fhoeben/sample-fitnesse-project/blob/master/.gitignore. (For Subversion you can set an svn-ignore property instead of using a .gitignore file)

I expect you want to exclude at least:

```
fitnesse-standalone.jar
FitNesseRoot/**/*.zip
FitNesseRoot/files/testResults
FitNesseRoot/files/testProgress
FitNesseRoot/ErrorLogs
FitNesseRoot/FitNesse
FitNesseRoot/RecentChanges*
updateDoNotCopyOverList
updateList
properties
```

Comment: If we use an external version control for managing the wiki pages, can we compare the versions of wiki pages using any User Interface?

Comment: Yes, using the tools available for that VCS (e.g. sourcetree, tortoise svn). But if you mean in the wiki: no.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for UI to compare wiki pages